# Сомнения в постановке знаков препинания

Tags: запятые

Скажите,пожалуйста, нужны ли запятые?
Супружеская пара(,)Джим и Делла(,)бедно жили

Answer (score 2):

Лучше так:

*Супружеская пара **Джим и Делла** / жили бедно.*

1. Приложение "супружеская пара" перед определяемым сочетанием ***Джим и Делла*** не обособляется. Согласование подлежащего и сказуемого **во мн. числе.**
2. При обособлении **согласование** будет некорректным, а **уточняющие отношения** не кажутся обоснованными.
3. **Для сравнения** (пример согласования **в ед. числе** при обособлении):

*Скромно и серьезно **присутствовала** никем из читателей вчера не замеченная **супружеская пара**, Бен Достойный Утки и Роуз Достойная Утки.*

Comment: А если супруги Джим и Белла бедно жили? Знаки препинания нужны? Кстати,спасибо большое за ответ 

Comment: Ничего не изменится, это тоже простое предложения без обособления. У вас инверсия (бедно жили), а  необходимость такой перестановки нужно смотреть по тексту.  Джим и Белла бЕдно жили. Джим и Белла  жили бЕдно.  Ударение меняется.